# When do Kubernetes Cronjobs create2 jobs or none at all?

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I am reading Kubernetes In Action book.

At the end of chapter 4, the author states:

> In normal circumstances, a CronJob always creates only a single Job
> for each execution configured in the schedule, but it may happen that
> two jobs are created at the same time, or none at all.

Does this really happen? When are the causes for this?

Edit: My question is a duplicate of this one [Why in kubernetes cron job two jobs might be created, or no job might be created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691278/why-in-kubernetes-cron-job-two-jobs-might-be-created-or-no-job-might-be-created)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691278/why-in-kubernetes-cron-job-two-jobs-might-be-created-or-no-job-might-be-created